# Call to action: Review and Vote to Close and/or Edit

Tags: discussion, voting, review-page

A few months ago, the diamond moderators made a decision <sup>(citation needed)</sup> to back off a little bit on unilaterally closing questions.  We did this to

1. Encourage community moderation
2. To not impose our will upon the site

A side effect of this is that [Review Queue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review) has been growing.  We have a decent number of 3k users, but only a handful who review on a consistent basis.  We can't seem to get past three close votes on most questions.

Drupal Answers is moderated by the community, and we need more more participation to keep the quality up.

3k users need to start reviewing more and taking action.

- Vote up/down questions
- Edit bad questions, especially those that appear to be from ESL users
- Vote to close on questions that really need it, and leave some comments to encourage more information and/or explain what is bad.

Remember, the diamond moderators are really just janitors. Flagging should only be used for posts that can't be salvaged.

And also keep in mind that just because something is in the [Close Vote](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/close) queue, doesn't mean it has to be closed.  If you can edit it into shape, please do so.

Comment: As a side note, lowering the close threshold is more than likely not a possibility.

Comment: I usually see the review queues empty. On the other hand, there is my name on most of the closed questions, so maybe I'm just doing it right ;)

Comment: @Mołot. I believe this is because you frequently cast the first close vote (this is what *places* the post in the review queue).  Since you can't vote again, the queue will appear empty to you. I'll try to cast some more first votes too.

Comment: @GisleHannemyr Most of my votes have at least 2 follow-up votes, so even if I'm not always right, I guess I'm not doing a terrible job here.

Comment: Recently, I flagged some questions to close as these are off-topic and flagged is accepted by moderator. But I did not see my name in close question. It mean, I have low reputation for this.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola once you reach 3k, your name also included by accessing the close votes review queue, but not by flagging.

Comment: @Bala, thanks. I was also thinking same that I have low reputation.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola Flagging and close-voting are different.  And, even if a moderator marks a flag as helpful, they may not actually do anything.

Comment: We're down to 0 :D (As I see the queues, at least)

Comment: "If you can edit it into shape, please do so." - especially important in case of questions marked as "unclear what you're asking". If you understand it, if it's clear for you, edit it so the others could understand it, too!