# Why am I recently getting "Review" items?

Tags: support

Did I get enough rep to be able to review stuff? Or why do I randomly get stuff to review every few days now?

Comment: maybe before people with review race war, I think now they stopped the war, that's why you get a chance to review nowadays.

Comment: @Bala see my answer

Answer (score 2):

According to [this call to action](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2773/16495) queues were not even near to empty at December 10 2013. Then MPD called us to action (not race war! action called my moderator), and community did it's best to reply to that call.

Now, a lot of time passed since that call, and we are no longer so urgent about queues. It wears off after some time, that's normal. The more people review, the less need for calls like that, so it's good we have you reviewing.

Comment: ah ok this makes sense. thanks